# Get last item from a list as integer/float

Tags: python, list

Very simple question, I have a list like so:

```
a = [0,1,2,3,4,5,7,8]
```

and I need to get the last item in that list as a float or an integer. If I do:

```
print a[0], a[4]
```

I get `1 5`, which is fine, but if i try to retrieve the last item with:

```
print a[-1:]
```

I get the *list* `[8]` instead of the *number* `8`. I know that I could just use `print a[len(a)-1]` but it feels kind of overkill and now I also have the doubt of why is `a[-1:]` returning a list instead of an element?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to do `a[-1]` to get the last item.  See below:

```
>>> a = [0,1,2,3,4,5,7,8]
>>> a[-1]
8
>>>
```

Having the colon in there makes it *slice* the list, not index it.

Here are some references on lists and slicing/indexing them:

http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#lists

[Explain Python's slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/pythons-slice-notation)

Comment: Can't believe I didn't think of that. Thanks for the immediate answer. Cheers.

Answer (score 3):

Just do:

```
>>> a = [0,1,2,3,4,5,7,8]
>>> a[-1]
 8
```

You were slicing the list not getting last item.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way:

```
>>> a = [0,1,2,3,4,5,7,8]
>>> a[-1]
8
```

why is a[-1:] returning a list instead of an element?

```
>>> list[-1:] # returns list
    [8]
>>> list[-1]  # returns value
    8
```

we also can `use pop()`. But it removes last element from the list.So it depends what you want to do.

```
list.pop()
```